# Install SQL Server Extension on VS code but getting "this extension is globally enabled"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a problem that I cannot install the [`mssql extension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15) on VS Code. It shows that

> this extension is globally enabled.

This problem is not only for `mssql extension` but also for all other extensions.

Comment: what extension do you mean? there are some of them.

Comment: You wrote "mssql" but tagged your question [tag:mysql]. These are two different products, even though they both begin with the letter "m." I have edited your question and tags to make it more clear that you're using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: If you look for a VSCode extension to manage SQL Server, then you came to the wrong direction. Microsoft has an official product called Azure Data Studio for that purpose, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15